# Regex replace not working the same in node as in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to escape all commas in a sentence. My replace isn't working correctly in node, however in chrome console it's working fine.

Does anyone have a solution to this? It seems to be the same for all characters

`let sentence = 'Hello, my name is Jim'`

`sentence.replace(/,/g, '\\,');`

OUTPUT ON NODE TERM: `'Hello\\, my name is Jim'`

The final string should be `'Hello\, my name is Jim'`

Also, if anyone had an explanation as to why this works everywhere except the node console that'd be good!

Many thanks

Comment: Please include *in the question* sufficient code from Node to re-create the issue. (Images of code are not helpful).

Comment: I have included a screenshot, can't you see it? Here is code: `const sentence = 'Hello, my name is Jim'`. Then I do `sentence.replace(/,/g, '\\,');`

Comment: it should be like this [sentence = sentence.replace(/,/g, '\\,');] and const should change to let

Comment: this will not change anything in the `sentence` because that is a `const` in browser it just outputs the result. And what exactly means doesn't work? that outputs twice `\\` ?

Comment: Yes I know that's just for demonstration purpose with output

Comment: what @Richard means is that you should edit your post and add the code instead of the image. And don't add the code in the comments.

Comment: The output in the REPL is escaped, if you use `console.log(sentence.replace(...))` it'll show what you expected.

Comment: @robertklep that comment should be an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That behaviour is explained [here](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_customizing_repl_output):

> By default, `repl.REPLServer` instances format output using the `util.inspect()` method before writing the output to the provided `Writable` stream (`process.stdout` by default).

In other words, this is what's happening "under the hood":

```
const { inspect } = require('util')

let sentence = 'Hello, my name is Jim'

console.log( inspect( sentence.replace(/,/g, '\\,') ) );
```

`inspect` escapes strings, so `\` becomes `\\` (and the string also gets surrounded by quotation marks).

You can work around that by outputting the string yourself from the REPL:

```
console.log( sentence.replace(/,/g, '\\,') );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect both Chrome and Node.js work the same, they just print the result differently.

When you just print the length of the string instead of the string itself, it is probably the same.

Node.js then prints the string in a format that is easy to copy & paste. It is a valid JavaScript string literal.

Chrome on the other hand prints all characters as they are, possibly marking the string start and end by using different colors. When you copy the string from the JavaScript console to the clipboard and then paste it somewhere, the backslash might double.